# Build error: The command "tsc --comments --module AMD --sourcemap --target ES3 " exited with code 1

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build, typescript

I was receiving the following error on build in a Visual Studio HTML Application with TypeScript project:

```
The command "tsc  --comments --module AMD --sourcemap --target ES3 " exited with code 1.    ProjectName
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem I had was that the `index.ts` file was not referenced in the project file.

Fix was to add to `ProjectName.csproj`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <TypeScriptCompile Include="index.ts" />
</ItemGroup>
```